# Allure interlocking floating floor ultra tile. How do I get the final pieces on the opposite or interior walls to lock into place.

Tags: tile

What is the best way to get the "final" pieces to interlock when you are either up against the opposite wall or any interior wall.

Comment: Allure and similar products don't go tight against any wall.  You leave a small gap for expansion that gets covered by molding.  So the final row should interlock just like any other row.  Is there a specific problem you're encountering with the installation that prevents interlocking the last pieces?